# issues when wrapping text around rotated text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create info graphics / data panels on a hobby site that I'm working on. I'm wishing to display text for one of the stat totals vertically rotated with supporting text wrapping around this however I'm having great difficulty getting this aligned correctly.

Instead of pasting code I can show my work in progress page at:

http://www.footy-results.co.uk/

The info graphic panel that I can't get to work is the '148 TEAMS' ... hopefully the problem is obvious to css wizards!

Any hints or tips would be much appreciated and anyone who can help me resolve this issue will be credited on the site when I launch!

Comment: transformation in css is done in a position of the referred element, not the position of the referred container  can you can a fiddle for this, i can do that...

Comment: @footyr one advise for your website (not question related) But use `margin:0;` on your body, so the website doesn't get the white space around..

Comment: hi C Travel ... thanks for the advice - I've just applied your suggestion and its looking better so thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution fou you but its not 100% clean. In my opinion its just not allowed to use negative margin but I can't find another solution. And furthermore you have do define height and width of the element...

You have to place the rotaded `<span>` element into anothe `<div>`. Then you can position the `<div>` properly and the text is floating around it. Here the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="infoPanel">
    <span class="infoPanelVertical">
         <div class="spanwrapper">
             <span class="infoNumberVertical">148 TEAMS</span>
         </div> your text here...
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.spanwrapper {
    float: left;
    height: 157px;
    position: relative;
    width: 48px;
}

.infoNumberVertical {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border: 1px dotted #DDDDDD;
    color: #1A3C7B;
    float: left;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: -56px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    width: 150px;
}
```

The problem is that you have to  give a hight and a width to the wrapping `<div>` or the span in it otherwise the text does not know where it should get floated. If you don't define any width or height the text is just wrapping around the rotated text which is a big rectangle.
I you use a CMS or want to fill in the content dynamicly this is a bad solution. But you could also define the width and height trough js but thats kinda hacky solution I think.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and the explanation ... this works well! These items will eventually be getting filled dynamically however there won't be so many that it will cause too much of an issue to apply separate styles for each. Anyway this really works great for me so thanks again for your help!