# Text rotation with wrapping in bootstrap card

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a card with some text

```
    <div class="card border-info">
        <div id = "heading_card" class="card-header">
            a very long string of text which is not getting wrapped in a card
        </div>
    </div>
```

that has been rotated using the css

```
#heading_card{
    text-orientation: mixed;
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;    
}
```

However because I have not specified a height and text is very long, it does not wrap, resulting in a very long vertical container. I have tried putting it in a card group and it did not help - since the rest of the cards in the card group shares the same height, they also became very tall.

I've checked out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977565/issues-when-wrapping-text-around-rotated-text), it requires manually setting a height. For now I added to the following to `heading_card`,

```
height: 150px;
```

but I don't want to to hard code things. Another idea I had was simply using breaks so that the text is split over several lines, but it feels clumsy. Is there an alternative?

Comment: you will need `@keyframes` in css for this to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about assigning a percentage to the height rather than fixed pixels and then adding a word break:

```css
#heading_card{
    text-orientation: mixed;
    writing-mode: vertical-lr;
    word-break: break-word;
    max-height: 35%;
}
```

```html
   <div class="card border-info">
        <div id = "heading_card" class="card-header">
            a very long string of text which is not getting wrapped in a card
        </div>
    </div>
```